# How do you DESCRIBE a Hive table with the same name as a Hive keyword?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I encountered a Hive table with the name "comment". When I try `describe comment;`
I get this error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'describe' 'comment' '<EOF>' in describe statement
```

I also tried:

```
describe `comment`;
describe `db_name.comment`;
describe db_name.`comment`;
describe 'comment';
etc.
```

but I keep getting the above error or a "Table ... does not exist" error. I looked at the [Hive DDL Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL) but could not figure out how to DESCRIBE the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Hive 0.12 but the bug has been fixed in Hive 0.14. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6187 for details.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. There must be something else which is causing this. I tried this on my machine and it is working fine. Most probably, you have created the table with some other name. What does Hive show when you do **show tables**?

[image]

Comment: This definitely doesn't work on Hive 0.7. Probably this bug was fixed in the newer versions of Hive.